# Does tdengine support full-text retrieval?

Tags: full-text-search, tdengine

Does tdengine support full-text retrieval? How can I use this feature? I didn't find the relevant configuration in the configuration file.

Answer (score 0):

it will be ready in TDengine3.0

Comment: Do you have a source or citation for this claim?